# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i know that there's so many questions about this but sorry im really confuse about this error...

i created a login page and i used ajax for the POST Request..what happens is when i used this

```
$.ajax({
 url:'../ajax/checklogin.php',
 type:'POST',
 dataType:'JSON',
 data:$('form').serialize(),   
  success: function(result){
  $.post("../www/login.php",{ users_id: JSON.parse(result.users_id)}).done(window.location.href='../www/index.php');
  }
});
```

the `$.post` is working but when i tried to add another field to parse i got this error.. the error is on users_active.. for some reason i dont have any idea why i got the error

```
$.post("../www/login.php",{ users_id: JSON.parse(result.users_id),users_active: JSON.parse(result.users_active)}).done(window.location.href='../www/index.php');
```

the other field are  fine but the only field that gives me error is the users_active.. i even check the json array that is being returned they are valid json...

Comment: Why the `JSON.parse()`? `result` should already be an object

Comment: the reason i use parse is to remove the " " to make it a string..

Comment: if i console `console.log(JSON.parse(result.users_active));` i got the error title but for the users_id when i console `console.log(JSON.parse(result.users_id));` instead of getting `"12345"` the result is `12345` thats the reason why i use parse to remove the " " to make it a plain string.

Comment: Can you show us the content of `result`? (`console.log(result);`)

Comment: `{"id":"26","users_id":"201710001","users_username":"123","users_active":"active"}`  this is the result of `console.log` i just removed some fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse doesn't remove quotes ("), but converts your data into objects, booleans or strings - if they were valid json before (not just the values of the properties, which you have passed). See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

If you want to assure that you pass integers or strings (or whatever you need) to your ajax post, just use the adequate javascript functions, like parseInt() or String().

See here an example with your data:

```
var result = {
  "id":"26",
  "users_id":
  "201710001",
  "users_username":"123",
  "users_active":"active"
  };

$.post("../www/login.php", { 
    users_id: parseInt(result.users_id),
  users_active: String(result.users_active) 
  }).done(window.location.href='../www/index.php');
```

Comment: ohh isee.. cause when i search on how to remove those qoute it says that use JSON.parse to remove it so thats the reason why i used it.. sorry im barely new in using json.. so i have any knowledge on how it works.. thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.parse()` takes a string and turns it into a JavScript object.

You are lucky, that `JSON.parse("12345")` can be converted to `new Number("12345")`, which is indeed an integer.

`result.users_active` is already a JavaScript object (or array) or maybe a String, which not represents a JSON object, so the parse will result in a syntax error as stated in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp.

I assume, you need `JSON.stringify()`, but to assure that, you should post some code or your result object.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Edit: Now that I have seen the object, `"active"` is a simple string and you can't strip the quotes. So just use `users_active: result.users_active`.

Comment: when i tried to use JSON.stringify(result.users_active) the result is "active" but what i want to is to remove those double qoute...is there any way to remove those?.. the reason i use JSON.parse is to remove those double qoute like instead of resulting to "12345" it give me 12345.... without double qoute..

Comment: You can only strip quotes from numbers or booleans. `"active"` is a string and can't exist without quotes because it would otherwise be a reference to a variable named `active`.

Comment: ohh isee.. cause when i search on how to remove those qoute it says that use JSON.parse to remove it so thats the reason why i used it.. sorry im barely new in using json.. so i have any knowledge on how it works.. thanks for the info...